# Axios.put only updates some fields, not all

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, heroku, axios

I followed this tutorial that uses nodejs, mysql2, express, vuejs:

https://mfikri.com/en/blog/nodejs-express-mysql-vue

but I used my own database and tables.

My problem is that when I send an axios.put request, the database will only update for some fields, not all.

My users table in the database was built with:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
userid INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255),
password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
role INT(11),
emailconfirmed TINYINT(1),
TIER INT(11)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

This database is living in a Heroku ClearDB Resource

My api in my Express backend looks like:

```
await axios.put(
          `http://localhost:5000/users/${this.$route.params.id}`,
          {
            email: this.userEmail,
            role: this.userRole,
            emailconfirmed: this.userEmailConfirmed,
            tier: this.userTier,
          }
        );
```

When I send my request either through POSTMAN or vuejs, I can update role or tier without any issue, but when I try to change email or emailconfirmed, I get:

affectedRows: 1
changedRows:0

I don't get it and I can't find anything to help answer the question.

Please help me.

Comment: Ok, so i get the fact you're using a put request on localhost:5000/users, but could you share how you handle your put request please ?

Comment: I don’t know what that means. It sounds like your asking for how Heroku deals with put requests, which I don’t know if I can affect. Or, what I’m doing with the data once it gets back? I don’t think that’s your question, as it isn’t updating the database and would just return what’s in the database. Maybe you’re asking what my connection to the database looks like? I can’t see that being your question as some fields do update.

Comment: @everstrivin, if you followed the article that you mentioned, it has some JavaScript files like ```productModel.js``` or ```product.js``` or ... in the back-end (Node + express) part of site. If you have problems with updating your data you must check that files in your project to see what is wrong or put the codes in the question, So that other developers could help you. If you do not handle the back-end codes yourself, So read the documentation of the tools that handle it for you.

Comment: Of course. I was missing the additional fields in my model for updating. I purposefully left those minimal to update later. Then I forgot about them.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i'm glad you find out what was missing. That piece of code you shared on your answer was what i expected to see. When you get a good response from your db, but wrong value get updated / inserted, always double check your request handling and database query, good luck for your project anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check my model files in the Backend. I didn't fully set them up to update all the fields.

My code looked like:

```
// Update User to Database
export const updateUserById = (data, id, result) => {
    db.query("UPDATE users SET role = ?, tier = ? WHERE userid = ?", [data.role, data.tier, id], (err, results) => {             
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            result(err, null);
        } else {
            result(null, results);
        }
    });   
}
```

So to fix it, obviously I need to add email and emailconfirmed to the SET expression.

Rookie mistake.

Thanks @hamid-davodi